# How does this asm for a stdcall function clean args from the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention, stdcall

I have simple code. `StdCall` is `__stdcall` and `CdeclCall` is `__cdecl`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __stdcall StdCall(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
 
int __cdecl CdeclCall(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    StdCall(10,20);
    CdeclCall(10,20);
    printf("Done");
    return 0;

}
```

Part of Disassabmbly of main() for StdCall (Main **does not** clear stack for StdCall)

```
push    20                  ; 00000014H
push    10                  ; 0000000aH
call    ?StdCall@@YGHHH@Z           ; StdCall
```

Part of Disassabmbly of main() for CdeclCall (Main **does** clear stack for CdeclCall)

```
push    20                  ; 00000014H
push    10                  ; 0000000aH
call    ?CdeclCall@@YAHHH@Z         ; CdeclCall
add esp, 8   ; Stack cleared here
```

---

Now, it is responsibility of StdCall to remove its args from the stack, but disassembly does not show any code which pops the ags to clear / clean the stack.

Disassembly for  StdCall

```
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
    mov ecx, 48                 ; 00000030H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    add eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 8
```

Is it runtime activity to generate clearing stack code for `__stdcall` or I have taken concept wrongly?

Comment: The old term for the callee restoring the stack pointer was pacscal calling convention, but in your case it's now __stdcall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the `ret 8` instruction - 8 is the number of bytes to add to the stack pointer after popping the return address.

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret

See also [What is the meaning and usage of __stdcall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306414/what-is-the-meaning-and-usage-of-stdcall/26651396#26651396) for more about the `@` decorations on C functions names in Windows.

Comment: Wanted to elaborate for me, **return value** is getting stored in **register**. `ret` instruction will just pass the control. Is that right?

Comment: @pranitkothari yes that's right. The return value is already in `eax`.

Comment: (edited question & answer to make a better duplicate for [MessageBox program in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66323292)).  PS, Mark, you can @reply to someone who's edited a post, even if they haven't commented.  Agreed it would be nice if there was a PM mechanism other than figuring out how to "invite someone to chat" which I think might be possible without posting a comment anywhere, but you'd have to start a chat room so I can't be bothered.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks again.  I guess I was thrown off since the `@` didn't offer an autocomplete option like it usually does.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's weird like that.  For some reason autocomplete doesn't work for people who only edited, not commented.  I guess it's just a factor of running client-side.