# MessageBox program in x86 assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, calling-convention, stdcall

Having a simple `MessageBox` program like that:

```
NULL          EQU 0                             ; Constants
MB_DEFBUTTON1 EQU 0
MB_DEFBUTTON2 EQU 100h
IDNO          EQU 7
MB_YESNO      EQU 4

extern _MessageBoxA@16                          ; Import external symbols
extern _ExitProcess@4                           ; Windows API functions, decorated

global Start                                    ; Export symbols. The entry point

section .data                                   ; Initialized data segment
 MessageBoxText    db "Do you want to exit?", 0
 MessageBoxCaption db "MessageBox 32", 0

section .text                                   ; Code segment
Start:
 push  MB_YESNO | MB_DEFBUTTON2                 ; 4th parameter. 2 constants ORed together
 push  MessageBoxCaption                        ; 3rd parameter
 push  MessageBoxText                           ; 2nd parameter
 push  NULL                                     ; 1st parameter
 call  _MessageBoxA@16

 cmp   EAX, IDNO                                ; Check the return value for "No"
 je    Start

 push  NULL

 call  _ExitProcess@4
```

My question is:
Shouldn't we add appropriate value to the `esp` reg after calling the `MessageBoxA` to restore the stack to it's previous state? If so when calling `push  MessageBoxCaption` how much have to be added to the `esp` register (4?).

Comment: In x86, *almost every* Win32 API uses the `stdcall` calling convention (exceptions include `wsprintf()`, etc which have to use `cdecl` instead). [Under `stdcall`, **the callee, not the caller**, is responsible for cleaning up the call stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall). So, in this case, when calling `MessageBoxA`, you have to push 16 bytes onto the stack for its 4 parameters, and then `MessageBoxA` will pop those 16 bytes off the stack when it returns. The `@16` indicates that the parameters take up 16 bytes.