# C Calling Convention/Parameter Passing

Tags: c, assembly

Everywhere I looked ("Programming from the ground up", Wikipedia [x86 Calling Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), ...), it was said that C passes arguments through the stack. Yet, in the following C code

```
int func(int);

int main() {
    func(5);
    return 0;
}

int func(int a) {
    return a;
}
```

Argument a is passed through register %edi (used `gcc -S ex.c` to compile on Ubuntu 64 bit machine). I passed more arguments, the caller just uses more registers to pass the values.

Is that normal? Are the online resources I visited somehow outdated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "C passes arguments through the stack": wrong: it's implementation defined and depends on the compiler. If there are enough registers, the compiler may choose to pass by register to be more efficient

Comment: To go further, can we control the compiler's behavior in that regard? I want to call my own assembly routines with a C wrapper. Should I re-post?

Comment: You're compiling for the x86-64 System V calling convention.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989)/ (answer also includes the function-calling convention).  [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306414/what-is-the-meaning-and-usage-of-stdcall

Comment: Oh. A whole new world just opened up... (to me). Question answered.