# Calling a standard-library-function in MASM

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

I want to get started in MASM in a mixed C++/Assembly way.
I am currently trying to call a standard-library-function (e.g. printf) from a PROC in assembly, that I then call in C++.

I have the code working after I declared printf's signature in my cpp-file. But I do not understand why I have to do this and if I can avoid that.

My cpp-file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    extern int __stdcall foo(int, int);
}

extern int __stdcall printf(const char*, ...); // When I remove this line I get Linker-Error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol"

int main()
{
    foo(5, 5);
}
```

My asm-file:

```
.model flat, stdcall

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data

tstStr db "Mult: %i",0Ah,"Add: %i",0 ; 0Ah is the backslash - escapes are not supported

.code

foo PROC x:DWORD, y:DWORD

mov eax, x
mov ebx, y
add eax, ebx
push eax
mov eax, x
mul ebx
push eax
push OFFSET tstStr
call printf
ret

foo ENDP

END
```

**Some Updates**

In response to the comments I tried to rework the code to be eligible for the cdecl calling-convention. Unfortunatly this did not solve the problem (the code runs fine with the `extern` declaration, but throws an error without).

But by trial and error i found out, that the `extern` seems to force external linkage, even though the keyword should not be needed, because external linkage should be the [default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) for function declarations.

I can omit the declaration by using the function in my cpp-code (i.e. if a add a `printf("\0");` somewhere in the source file the linker is fine with it and everythings works correctly.

The new (but not really better) cpp-file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    extern int __cdecl foo(int, int);
}
extern int __cdecl printf(const char*, ...); // omiting the extern results in a linker error

int main()
{
    //printf("\0"); // this would replace the declaration
    foo(5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The asm-file:

```
.model flat, c

EXTERN printf :PROC

.data

tstStr db "Mult: %i",0Ah,"Add: %i",0Ah,0 ; 0Ah is the backslash - escapes are not supported

.code

foo PROC

push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp+8]
mov ebx, [ebp+12]
add eax, ebx
push eax
mov eax, [ebp+8]
mul ebx
push eax
push OFFSET tstStr
call printf
add esp, 12
pop ebp
ret

foo ENDP

END
```

Comment: `extern` in front of a function declaration probably doesn’t do what you think it does, because *it has no effect*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: _it has no effect_ is a rather strong statement, given that the code compiles with that declaration and does not compile without. Your comment may be true for a pure (Standard) C++ program, but this is a mix of C++ and assembly. Clearly the interaction between this compiler, this assembler and this linker works out in a way that `extern` must have done _something_.

Comment: @MSalters Removing the `extern` keyword won’t change anything (and is a red herring here) because function declarations are always implicitly extern. So, yes, it has no effect.

Comment: @MSalters Konrad's talking about the `extern`, not about the entire declaration.

Comment: I'm indeed a bit puzzled myself. Since `<stdio.h>` is included, there already is a declaration of `::std::printf` or `::printf`, as appropriate. But it's indeed a good thing to get clarified. @AnonymousAnonymous, dis it still work if you remove _just_ the `extern` ?

Comment: `printf` is inherently and must be `__cdecl` not `__stdcall` this is because `__stdcall` is callee stack cleanup and `printf` can't know inherently at link time what part of the stack will need cleaning up. [So it needs the caller cleaned up `__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Mgetz: On a linked page, an example shows that's not true: [`typedef BOOL (__stdcall *funcname_ptr)(void * arg1, const char * arg2, DWORD flags, ...);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @MSalters documentation can be wrong, read the page on `__stdcall`

Comment: @MSalters I have testet it out and it does make a difference. With `extern` it compiles just fine, but without I get the same linker error as before:  `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_printf" in function "_foo@8"`

Comment: @Mgetz You might be right, but changing everything to cdecl (asm-file and declarations) does not change anything

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651396) the exported name isn't `printf` it's likely `_printf` and you'll need to include the masm reference to the cstdlib and make sure your call follows calling convention,

Comment: @Mgetz Could you please elaborate? I feel like I do not really understand the term "include the masm reference to the cstdlib".

Comment: @Mgetz Oh. And changing `EXTERN printf :PROC` to `EXTERN _printf :PROC` doesn't help either

Comment: @Mgetz : The documentation isn't wrong with the example. Microsoft documents that the behaviour of *__stdcall* is to revert back to *__cdecl* in the case of a variadic function. It is legal to put `stdcall` on such a function. This behaviour is defined in the MS description of `__stdcall` _The __stdcall calling convention is used to call Win32 API functions. The callee cleans the stack, so **the compiler makes vararg functions __cdecl**. Functions that use this calling convention require a function prototype._. The example was simply to show how to use the `__stcall` modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that this has to do with the fact that Microsoft refactored the C library starting with VS 2015 and some of the C library is now inlined (including `printf`) and isn't actually in the default `.lib` files.

My guess is in this declaration:

```
extern int __cdecl printf(const char*, ...);
```

`extern` forces the old legacy libraries to be included in the link process. Those libraries contain the non-inlined function `printf`. If the *C++* code doesn't force the MS linker to include the legacy C library then the MASM code's use of `printf` will become unresolved.

I believe this is related to this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721059/call-c-standard-library-function-from-asm-in-visual-studio) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33725587/3857942) in 2015. If you want to remove `extern int __cdecl printf(const char*, ...);` from the *C++* code you may wish to consider adding this line to your MASM code:

```
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
```

Your MASM code would look like this if you are using CDECL calling convention and mixing *C/C++* with assembly:

```
.model flat, C      ; Default to C language
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data

tstStr db "Mult: %i",0Ah,"Add: %i",0 ; 0Ah is the backslash - escapes are not supported

.code

foo PROC x:DWORD, y:DWORD   
    mov eax, x
    mov ebx, y
    add eax, ebx
    push eax
    mov eax, x
    mul ebx
    push eax
    push OFFSET tstStr
    call printf
    ret
foo ENDP

END
```

Your C++ code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    extern int foo(int, int); /* __cdecl removed since it is the default */
}

int main()
{
    //printf("\0"); // this would replace the declaration
    foo(5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The alternative to passing the `includelib` line in the assembly code is to add `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` to the dependency list in the linker options of your Visual Studio project or the command line options if you invoke the linker manually.

---

### Calling Convention Bug in your MASM Code

You can read about the [CDECL calling convention for 32-bit Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019) code in the Microsoft documentation as well as this Wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). Microsoft summarizes the CDECL calling convention as:

> On x86 platforms, all arguments are widened to 32 bits when they are passed. Return values are also widened to 32 bits and returned in the EAX register, except for 8-byte structures, which are returned in the EDX:EAX register pair. Larger structures are returned in the EAX register as pointers to hidden return structures. Parameters are pushed onto the stack from right to left. Structures that are not PODs will not be returned in registers.
>
> The compiler generates prologue and epilogue code to save and restore the ESI, EDI, EBX, and EBP registers, if they are used in the function.

The last paragraph is important in relation to your code. The *ESI*, *EDI*, ***EBX***, and *EBP* registers are non-volatile and must be saved and restored by the called function if they are modified. Your code clobbers *EBX*, you must save and restore it. You can get MASM to do that by using the [`USES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proc?view=vs-2019) directive in a `PROC` statement:

```
foo PROC uses EBX x:DWORD, y:DWORD    
    mov eax, x
    mov ebx, y
    add eax, ebx
    push eax
    mov eax, x
    mul ebx
    push eax
    push OFFSET tstStr
    call printf
    add esp, 12               ; Remove the parameters pushed on the stack for
                              ;     the printf call. The stack needs to be
                              ;     properly restored. If not done, the function
                              ;     prologue can't properly restore EBX
                              ;     (and any registers listed by USES)
    ret
foo ENDP
```

`uses EBX` tell MASM to generate extra prologue and epilogue code to save *EBX* at the start and restore *EBX* when the function does a `ret` instruction. The generated instructions would look something like:

> ```
> 0000                    _foo:
> 0000  55                        push            ebp
> 0001  8B EC                     mov             ebp,esp
> 0003  53                        push            ebx
> 0004  8B 45 08                  mov             eax,0x8[ebp]
> 0007  8B 5D 0C                  mov             ebx,0xc[ebp]
> 000A  03 C3                     add             eax,ebx
> 000C  50                        push            eax
> 000D  8B 45 08                  mov             eax,0x8[ebp]
> 0010  F7 E3                     mul             ebx
> 0012  50                        push            eax
> 0013  68 00 00 00 00            push            tstStr
> 0018  E8 00 00 00 00            call            _printf
> 001D  83 C4 0C                  add             esp,0x0000000c
> 0020  5B                        pop             ebx
> 0021  C9                        leave
> 0022  C3                        ret
> ```

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you! I did not know about having to restore ebx - I just wish this would be stated in the documentation of cdecl and not on some other page, listimg all calling conventions... I mean, c'mon Microsoft :)

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a bit pointless, isn't it?

Linkers are often pretty dumb things. They need to be told that an object file requires `printf`. Linkers can't figure that out from a missing `printf` symbol, stupidly enough.

The C++ compiler will tell the linker that it needs `printf` when you write `extern int __stdcall printf(const char*, ...);`. Or, and that's the normal way, the compiler will tell the linker so when you actually call `printf`. But your C++ code doesn't call it!

Assemblers are also pretty dumb. Your assembler clearly fails to tell the linker that it needs `printf` from C++.

The general solution is not to do complex things in assembly. That's just not what assembly is good for. Calls from C to assembly generally work well, calls the other way are problematic.

Comment: Not my downvote, and I haven’t used MSVC in ages but does the declaration in source really tell the linker anything at all? On GCC/clang/… this would be wrong since symbol declaration and library linking are mostly orthogonal; and, in particular, the `printf` declaration in the C++ source file would have *no effect*.

Comment: well for one thing `__stdcall printf` doesn't exist in any library, the compiler should warn that variadic function parameters can't be used with `__stdcall`. While on x64 this doesn't actually change anything calling convention wise it does change the name exported still AFAIK