# 2 data types / identifiers before a function name in C?

Tags: c

I was browsing the source code for the old MyDoom malware but came across something I've never seen before in line 195 of [main.c](https://github.com/yorickdewid/MyDoom/blob/master/main.c). There are 2 identifiers before the function name. Can someone explain this to me? I'm only used to seeing 1 precursor identifier being the return type of a function like void func() or no precursor identifier for a object initialization function like classname().

Try not to be harsh on me, I'm new to C and came from Python so I wasn't prepared for a lot of the concepts.

```
DWORD _stdcall sync_visual_th(LPVOID pv)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are the names of two different languages.  You seem to be asking about C.  There is no language called "C/C++".

Comment: This provides some good detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306414/what-is-the-meaning-and-usage-of-stdcall