# What are these C++ Macros doing?

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, macros, filemaker

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand what these two macros are doing in this FileMaker Plugin Example.

```
#define FMX_PROC(retType)           retType __stdcall
#define FMX_PROCPTR(retType, name)  typedef retType (__stdcall *name)
```

So far I understand that they are both [macros](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/macros-and-its-types-in-c-cpp/), and that the `FMX_PROCPTR` is a pointer to a [function that takes those two arguments](https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/86726/), and that __stdcall is some sort of [calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306414/what-is-the-meaning-and-usage-of-stdcall) (decided to not dig to much into what that means).

What I don't understand are the ends of each lines, the parts that come after `FMX_PROC(retType)` and `FMX_PROCPT(retType, name)`.

It's possible that it is the spacing that is confusing me, but is `retType __stdcall` the return type for `FMX_PROC(retType)` ? Or is it giving the argument a type?

Somewhere else in the code `FMX_PROC(retType)` is used like this

```
static FMX_PROC(fmx::errcode) Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase( short /* funcId */, const fmx::ExprEnv& /* environment */, const fmx::DataVect& dataVect, fmx::Data& results )
```

Comment: `__stdcall ` defines the calling convention to be used, that's basically what's going on here.

Comment: These marcos are handled by the preprocessor by replacing strings (they are not functions). Wherever you see e.g. `FMX_PROC(fmx::errcode)` it is replaced to `fmx::errcode __stdcall`  (whatever you specify as `retType` followed by `__stdcall`). Regarding the meaning of `__stdcall` - the link you have in your question explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These macros are just to provide the calling-convention `__stdcall` into the function being defined, or a function pointer alias.

`__stdcall` is a non-standard compiler-intrinsic that ensures that functions documented with this attribute will be called with the [`stdcall` calling-convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170). This applies to the *function* itself.

So the macros respectively:

- `FMX_PROC` expands into `retType __stdcall`, which provides `__stdcall` to the function. E.g.

  ```cpp
  FMX_PROC(fmx::errcode) Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase(...)
  ```

  expands into:

  ```cpp
  fmx::errcode __stdcall Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase(...)
  ```
- `FMX_PROCPTR` expands into a *`typedef`* of a function pointer, that is also documented with `__stdcall`. This is necessary because function pointers don't normally carry calling conventions -- so the compiler doesn't implicitly know when a function expects a different calling convention. To bind a function marked `__stdcall` to a function pointer, the function pointer itself *must* carry this information (which is why this alias is needed).
  This expands into part of the function typedef:

  ```cpp
  FMX_PROCPTR(fmx::errcode,Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase)(...);
  ```

  will expand into

  ```cpp
  typedef fmx::errcode(__stdcall *Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase)(...);
  ```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation totally made sense

Answer (score 5):

Macros dont have return types. They aren't functions. To express that difference, such macros are called "Function-like macros", ie they look like functions but they aren't functions. The preprocessor replaces `FMX_PROC(fmx::errcode)` with `fmx::errcode __stdcall`. That is, this:

```
static FMX_PROC(fmx::errcode) Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase( short /* funcId */, const fmx::ExprEnv& /* environment */, const fmx::DataVect& dataVect, fmx::Data& results )
```

Gets expanded to this

```
static fmx::errcode __stdcall Do_FMmp_ConvertToBase( short /* funcId */, const fmx::ExprEnv& /* environment */, const fmx::DataVect& dataVect, fmx::Data& results )
```

Its a function declaration and `fmx::errcode` is its return type.