# Run-Time Check Failure #0

Tags: c, com

I am getting this run time error when using IID_IWebBrowser2 interface of CLSID_InternetExplorer.

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

This error happens when I am calling the navigate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the client (your program) uses the call convention different from what the server (COM object) expects. You need to check the COM interface methods declaration and adjust them accordingly.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696306/run-time-check-failure-0-loading-queryfullprocessimagename-from-kernel32-dll) for a solution of in fact the same problem.