# C++ Windows - How to get process path from its PID

Tags: c++, windows

How can I retrieve a process's fully-qualified path from its PID using C++ on Windows?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Call [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the process associated with your PID.  Once you have a handle to the process, call [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get its fully-qualified path.  Don't forget to call [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28VS.85%29.aspx) when you're finished using the process handle.

Here's a sample program that performs the required calls (replace 1234 with your PID):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h> // For access to GetModuleFileNameEx
#include <tchar.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _UNICODE
  #define tcout wcout
  #define tcerr wcerr
#else
  #define tcout cout
  #define tcerr cerr
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR * argv[])
{
  HANDLE processHandle = NULL;
  TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];

  processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, 1234);
  if (processHandle != NULL) {
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH) == 0) {
      tcerr << "Failed to get module filename." << endl;
    } else {
      tcout << "Module filename is: " << filename << endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
  } else {
    tcerr << "Failed to open process." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: most of modules turn to a failure in getting file path :(

Comment: Does it work when called from a 32bit environemet to get PID of a 64bit process ? I face problem and had to use **QueryFullProcessImageName** instead of **GetModuleFileNameEx**

Answer (score 3):

Some notes to Emerick Rogul's solution:

Don't forget to add 'psapi.lib' to linker (additional dependencies).

I also changed `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` to `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` because I got:

> Failed to open process.

If it's compiled as a 32 bit application it will fail to get the name of 64 bit processes ("Failed to get module filename.")

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have very much luck with [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is only available on Vista or higher. I was however able to get the path for a process by using [GetProcessImageFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It returns the windows kernel path but you can use [QueryDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to compare the device path returned by `GetProcessImageFilename` with its proper drive path.

This page shows how to normalize an windows kernel path returned by `GetProcessImageFilename` (see `NormalizeNTPath` function):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c48bcfb3-5326-479b-8c95-81dc742292ab/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696306/run-time-check-failure-0-loading-queryfullprocessimagename-from-kernel32-dll#696365 on how to define **QueryFullProcessImageName**  API call even if your SDK is not supporting it.

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName is not available in XP which is what I was targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `QueryFullProcessImageName`?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `GetModuleFileNameEx` returns the 299 error code (I don't know why)

The only method that works for all versions of Windows, including XP is in Nathan Moinvaziri answer:

check the provided url:

[Windows API to Get a Full Process Path](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c48bcfb3-5326-479b-8c95-81dc742292ab/)

Comment: Perhaps match my comment, from a 32bit process i fear it might fail to get path of a 64bit process. I had to use **QueryFullProcessImageName** instead of **GetModuleFileNameEx**