# get the full path from a PID using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need to get the full path from a PID.

I've checked this question [C++ Windows - How to get process path from its PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933113/c-windows-how-to-get-process-path-from-its-pid) 
and I wrote the following code:

```
 function GetFullPathFromPID(PID: DWORD): string;
 var
    hProcess: THandle;
    ModName : Array[0..MAX_PATH + 1] of Char;
 begin
   Result:='';
    hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False, PID);
    try
      if hProcess <> 0 then
       if GetModuleFileName(hProcess, ModName, Sizeof(ModName))<>0 then
         Result:=ModName
        else
         ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    finally
     CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
 end;
```

but always return this message:

> the specified module could not be found

How can I get the full path from a PID?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use the [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198(VS.85).aspx) function. From MSDN:

> **GetModuleFileName** Function
>
> Retrieves
>   the fully-qualified path for the file
>   that contains the specified module.
>   The module must have been loaded by
>   the current process.
>
> *To locate the file for a module that
>   was loaded by another process, use the
>   GetModuleFileNameEx function.*

Sample usage (`uses PsAPI`):

```
function GetPathFromPID(const PID: cardinal): string;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
    try
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, path, MAX_PATH) = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      result := path;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess)
    end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Win7:
I keep getting "access denied" errors even if run it as administrator or if I use the PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION option in the OpenProcess call.
Any idea why?

Comment: @Andreas It seems you posted this answer at the same time I did.

Comment: @user1580348: No, I beat you by more than 10 years.