# Delphi - How to kill a process by knowing its path?

Tags: delphi, process, kill

Until now I was using [this](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=266) function to kill a process. But what if I have three processes
of the same name and only one of them is the one that I want to kill? If I will do this:
 KillTask('csrss.exe') then it will kill the system process. I have the path of my process, how can I use this information to kill it?

Comment: Just pass to that `KillTask` function the full path. It should work for full path as well as just exe name.

Comment: does it work only for processes running under admin account or user account also will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over processes and check the path for each of them, then use the answer from this SO question (use GetModuleFileNameEx):

[get the full path from a PID using delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178443/get-the-full-path-from-a-pid-using-delphi)

If you launched the process then remember the PID or Handle and kill the specific one.