# GetBinaryType() returns the bitness to match the calling app

Tags: c#, ms-office, 32bit-64bit

I am [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203980/detect-whether-office-is-32bit-or-64bit-via-the-registry/36632170) to determine if Office is 32-bit or 64-bit. I am calling it from a C# app.

```
GetBinaryType(location, out bt)
```

The exact same code, calling this on winword.exe, returns either 32-bit or 64-bit, matching the bitness of my C# app. Is there something I need to do when running in 64-bit mode that it still returns 32-bit for Office?

[I've put a very simple sample program here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj0jpyv2x8vi17q/TestGetBinaryType.ZIP?dl=0)

The output running in x86 mode (on 64-bit Windows is):

> Running in 32-bit mode. GetBinaryType() returns SCS_32BIT_BINARY for
>   file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE

The output running in 64=bit mode is:

> Running in 64-bit mode. GetBinaryType() returns SCS_64BIT_BINARY for
>   file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE

I have 32-bit Office on my comouter.

code (if you don't want to download the zip):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace TestGetBinaryType
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\Winword.exe", RegistryRights.ReadKey))
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Could not find the registry key SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\Winword.exe");
                    return;
                }
                string location = key.GetValue(null) as string;
                if (!File.Exists(location))
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine($"File is not at specified location: {location}");
                    return;
                }

                BinaryType bt;
                if (!GetBinaryType(location, out bt))
                    throw new ApplicationException($"Could not read binary type from: {location}");
                Console.Out.WriteLine($"Running in {IntPtr.Size * 8}-bit mode.");
                Console.Out.WriteLine($"GetBinaryType() returns {bt} for file {location}");
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetBinaryType(string lpApplicationName, out BinaryType lpBinaryType);

        public enum BinaryType : uint
        {
            SCS_32BIT_BINARY = 0,   // A 32-bit Windows-based application
            SCS_64BIT_BINARY = 6,   // A 64-bit Windows-based application.
            SCS_DOS_BINARY = 1,     // An MS-DOS � based application
            SCS_OS216_BINARY = 5,   // A 16-bit OS/2-based application
            SCS_PIF_BINARY = 3,     // A PIF file that executes an MS-DOS � based application
            SCS_POSIX_BINARY = 4,   // A POSIX � based application
            SCS_WOW_BINARY = 2      // A 16-bit Windows-based application
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [Get type of binary on filesystem via C# running in 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338280/12767586) with similar issue.

Comment: I wonder, do you have `winword.exe` under both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: @GSerg I just looked - and no. Also, it's the same location for winword.exe in both cases (and I think Office blows up if you install both). Good question though.

Comment: possible duplicate: [GetBinaryType from Managed code gives opposite results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36486618/995714)?