# How to count processes starting from a full file name?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to get the process count starting from an executable full file name.

Here is my code:

```
function GetPathFromPID(const PID: cardinal): string;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
    try
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, path, MAX_PATH) = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      result := path;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess)
    end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

function ProcessCount(const AFullFileName: string): Integer;
var
  ContinueLoop: boolean;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := 0;
  while(ContinueLoop) do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(GetPathFromPID(FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID)) = UpperCase(AFullFileName)))
    then Result := Result + 1;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Caption := IntToStr(ProcessCount(Application.ExeName));
end;
```

`GetPathFromPID` function has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178443/get-the-full-path-from-a-pid-using-delphi) (Andreas Rejbrand's answer).

Running the application, I got EOSError exception ('System Error. Code: 87.'). As [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
>
> 87 (0x57)
>
> The parameter is incorrect.

The exception is raised from `GetPathFromPID` function, because the `hProcess <> 0` condition fails and `RaiseLastOSError` is executed.

Debugging I've noticed that 0 is passed to `GetPathFromPID` function as PID parameter but I don't understand what's wrong in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenProcess` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when you give it a PID of zero.

But also you may get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the process that you pass it to `OpenProcess` through `GetPathFromPID` function requires elevation.

Use this instated to make sure that you'r passing process have the same name only.

```
  while (ContinueLoop) do
  begin
    if SameText(ExtractFileName(AFullFileName), FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) then
    if ((UpperCase(GetPathFromPID(FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID)) = UpperCase(AFullFileName)))
     ....
  end;
```

Comment: you get my upvote for nice optimization I overlooked. although you did not explain why PID is 0. which is what the OP asked *"but I don't understand what's wrong in my code"*

Comment: This code also doesn't take short paths vs long paths into account. A short path and a long path can refer to the same file. There are better ways to compare paths for equality.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that `FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID` entry will be 0.

For example for the first process of `[System Process]` (check `FProcessEntry32.szExeFile`) has a PID of 0. I'm pretty sure this is the only entry with `th32ProcessID == 0`. See ["System Idle Process"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Idle_Process).

So simply check that `FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID <> 0` before you pass it on to `GetPathFromPID`.