# "Vista-only" heap corruption in a MFC application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks, mfc, windows-vista

Ours is a MFC application, which links to a win32 DLL. When the application invokes this DLL function, the argument "buffer" becomes a "Bad Pointer", after entering the function stack. This results in an application crash.

```
static MyClass* Instance(string& buffer);
```

I changed the argument type to "char *", but it only pushes the crash to next statement in the function. How to detect this heap corruption?

#### Few hints

- This crash is reproducible, even if I invoke this DLL function from the very start of our application (CWinApp constructor). Could this memory corruption be caused by loading of resources, manifest etc?
- The crash is ocurring in Vista and Win7, but not in XP.
- Both these projects were recently migrated from Visual Studio 2002 to VS2008.

#### Code that invokes the function

```
CString data = "some string";
string str = data.GetBuffer();
data.ReleaseBuffer();
MyClass *obj = MyClass::Instance(str);
```

Comment: What is the target os bit version? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Its a 32 bit application

Comment: Post code that shows the call to Instance.  Are both exe and dll using shared crt of the same type (multithread dll/single thread dll)?

Comment: Posted invoking code. Both exe and dll are using shared CRT of multithread dll

Comment: Does the memory that the string has allocated actually change during the invocation of Instance?  View the string contents in the memory window - do not rely on the quickwatch window for str.  Note that you should be able to assign data to str like "str = (LPCTSTR) data;" and then the ReleaseBuffer call can be removed.

Comment: As I said, it now crashes in the next statement that allocates a memory.

Comment: @e I'm getting this WARNING, while building the DLL. Any clues?

`LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two mistakes:

1. Couple of custom built C++ files were not compiled with MD switch. We had to add -MD to the custom build script to make the CRT consistant with other objects.
2. There were LNK2005 conflicts between LIBCMT.LIB and MSVCRT.LIB, which were otherwise ignored due to the /FORCE switch. We resolved these conflicts by removing LIBCMT.LIB in Linker->Input

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is wrong usage of [calling conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297654/what-is-stdcall) or a CRT mismatch (i go with calling conventions).

Try building a stub DLL with the same function signature (which does nothing) and make it work with your MFC app.

Here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/rsLoadtimeDLL.aspx)...

HTH