# Typedef with two sets of brackets?

Tags: c++

I have come across a typedef in some code which is this:

```
typedef void (NE_API *NeWindowProcCallback)(void* hWnd, NEuint uMsgId, NEuint wParam, NEuint64 lParam);
```

however, I am unfamiliar with this syntax. can anyone explain this?

Also, if I jump to the declaration of NE_API, I find this:

```
#   define NE_API __stdcall
```

I thought this may be relevant to the answer, and an explanation of this also would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

That is the typedef of a function pointer for which the function which returns `void`, has `__stdcall` calling convention, and accepts four parameters. So you can assign the address of any function which has this signature to a variable of type `NeWindowProcCallback`. This variable can then be passed as a parameter to other functions which expect a callback function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) for more details on how function pointers can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what __stdcall is here:
[What is __stdcall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297654/what-is-stdcall)
As for the typedef - this is the way to typedef a function. Now the type NeWindowProcCallback will be a pointer to a function taking arguments of type (void* hWnd, NEuint uMsgId, NEuint wParam, NEuint64 lParam).

So you can do:

```
void  foo(void* hWnd, NEuint uMsgId, NEuint wParam, NEuint64 lParam);


int main() {
  NeWindowProcCallback my_func = foo;
  ....
  // use the pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NeWindowProcCallback` is type for a function pointer. It takes the parameters `void* hWnd, NEuint uMsgId, NEuint wParam, NEuint64 lParam`, and returns `void`.

`__stdcall` is the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), which determines how arguments should be passed in the generated calling assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

the typedef defines *NeWindowProcCallback* as a type that stores a pointer to a function that returns *void* and takes (void* hWnd, NEuint uMsgId, NEuint wParam, NEuint64 lParam) as parameters