# Strange typedef definition C++

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)

```
TE0300_Open = (_TE0300_Open)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "TE0300_Open");
typedef int (WINAPI *_TE0300_Open)(unsigned int* PHandle, int CardNo);
```

Can someone explain me what this piece of code does? I know that `typedef` is used to assign alternative names to existing types but I don't understand this case at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typedef function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) and [Typedef with two sets of brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515739/typedef-with-two-sets-of-brackets)

Answer (score 4):

`typedef int (WINAPI *_TE0300_Open)(unsigned int* PHandle, int CardNo);`

This line typedefs a function pointer to a `WINAPI` calling convention function returning an `int`, and taking an `unsigned int *` and an `int`. The function pointer type is given the alias `_TE0300_Open`.

Consider the following example:

```
typedef void (*func)();

void foo (func f) //notice we have a nice type name here
{
    cout << "Calling function...";
    f();
}

void bar(){}

int main()
{
    foo (bar);
}
```

I believe C++11 added support for less icky syntax when using function pointers as well:

```
using func = void (*)();
```

As for your `GetProcAddress` call, this loads a function from a library. You assign it to a function pointer, and you can use that function pointer as you would the original function.

In your example, you can now call `TE0300_Open` as you would normally call `_TE0300_Open`. It should also be noted that `_TE0300_Open` is a name that is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't so strange after all, I just didn't fully understand the `typedef` usage.

Answer (score 2):

It's declaring a typedef, `_TE0300_Open`, for a function-pointer.