# Can I use __stdcall convention while using Xerces-C 3.0? I get linker errors

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, xerces, stdcall

In my project it is crucial I use __stdcall. However, I get this:

> 1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl xercesc_3_0::XMLString::release(unsigned short * *,class xercesc_3_0::MemoryManager * const)" (?release@XMLString@xercesc_3_0@@SAXPEAPEAGQEAVMemoryManager@2@@Z)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char * __cdecl xercesc_3_0::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const * const,class xercesc_3_0::MemoryManager * const)" (?transcode@XMLString@xercesc_3_0@@SAPEADQEBGQEAVMemoryManager@2@@Z)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned short * __cdecl xercesc_3_0::XMLString::transcode(char const * const,class xercesc_3_0::MemoryManager * const)" (?transcode@XMLString@xercesc_3_0@@SAPEAGQEBDQEAVMemoryManager@2@@Z)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const xercesc_3_0::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale" (?fgXercescDefaultLocale@XMLUni@xercesc_3_0@@2QBDB)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class xercesc_3_0::MemoryManager * xercesc_3_0::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager" (?fgMemoryManager@XMLPlatformUtils@xercesc_3_0@@2PEAVMemoryManager@2@EA)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class xercesc_3_0::DOMImplementation * __cdecl xercesc_3_0::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(unsigned short const *)" (?getDOMImplementation@DOMImplementationRegistry@xercesc_3_0@@SAPEAVDOMImplementation@2@PEBG@Z)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_0::XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint" (?fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint@XMLUni@xercesc_3_0@@2QBGB)
>   1>ExchangeParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_0::XMLUni::fgDOMXMLDeclaration" (?fgDOMXMLDeclaration@XMLUni@xercesc_3_0@@2QBGB)

Any help?

Comment: What is your OS? __stdcall is for win32 API see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297654/what-is-stdcall

Answer (score 0):

Xerces is [open source](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi), so why not just compile your own variant that uses `__stdcall` as the default convention, then you won't have the linkage errors.

It even comes with projects for every Windows IDE (including MSVC, which it appears you are using), so its merely a matter of loading it up, change one global option and hitting compile (you may need to change some places where `__cdecl` must be explicitly used, but the compiler will error on these locations when you build it).

Comment: I tried compiling using __stdcall, but nevertheless I get same errors. It seems that these methods explicitly use __cdecl convention. Is there any way to bypass this problem in any other way? Thanks

Comment: @user1266041: if these methods explicitly need `__cdecl` and you need to make the definitions in the header(s) explicitly state this via the `__cdecl` function attribute