# Using C++ DLL in Excel VBA

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I created the `MathFuncsDll.dll` from https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms235636.aspx without issues.
I can use the math functions in a different C++ project also without issues.

Now I want to use these functions in Excel VBA. I tried:

```
Public Declare Function DLL_Import_Add Lib "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MathFuncsDll.dll" Alias "Add" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double

Sub test()
    MsgBox DLL_Import_Add(2.1, 3.3)
End Sub
```

But I am receiving a `Run-time error '453'` The DLL entry point cannot be found.

How can I solve that problem?

MathFuncsDll.h:

```
// MathFuncsDll.h
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace MathFuncs
{
    // This class is exported from the MathFuncsDll.dll
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b);
        // Returns a - b
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Subtract(double a, double b);
        // Returns a * b
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Multiply(double a, double b);
        // Returns a / b
        // Throws const std::invalid_argument& if b is 0
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

MathFuncsDll.cpp:

```
// MathFuncsDll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I assume you know what you are doing** when calling a C++ library from a VB program, I am referring to [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx).

---

The problem is that C++ names are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

If you take a look at the exported functions names (for example with `dumpbin /EXPORTS MathFuncsDll.dll`, they are something like these:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001000 ?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z
      2    1 00001030 ?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z
      3    2 00001020 ?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z
      4    3 00001010 ?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z
```

My output will differ from yours, but it suffices to show that there are no simple names like `Add`.

Usually you avoid this mess with the use of the modifier `extern "C"`.
With Microsoft compiler, class memebers names seem to be always mangled, so it is useless here.

You can workaround this in four ways:

**1. Define a [`DEF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) file that rename the functions**

```
LIBRARY MathFuncsDll
EXPORTS
   Add=?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z
   ...
```

**2. Use the correct alias in your VBA declaration**

```
Public Declare Function DLL_Import_Add Lib "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MathFuncsDll.dll" Alias "?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SAHHH@Z" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double
```

**3. Import by ordinal, using something like `Alias "#1"`**

```
Public Declare Function DLL_Import_Add Lib "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MathFuncsDll.dll" Alias "#1" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double
```

**4. Define global stub functions that call their equivalents**

```
extern "C" MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b)
{
   return MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(a, b); 
}
```

and export them.

None of this is perfect, keep in mind that mangled names are compiler specific, if you use them and change/update the compiler, things may break up.

Also ordinals are not fixed, unless you use a *DEF* file (that again need the mangled name).

The last option is useful to change calling convention and won't change the way the original functions are exported, thus allowing access to both C++ and non C++ programs.

Comment: Thats it! I tried `Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z` but I forgot the `?` at the beginning. I also did that in C and defined the name of the functions in a DLL with a DEF file and there it was written the other way around: `name_in_dll = name_in_c`. Should that be flipped in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C"
{
// This class is exported from the MathFuncsDll.dll
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        MATHFUNCSDLL_API double __stdcall Add(double a, double b);
        // Returns a - b
        MATHFUNCSDLL_API double __stdcall Subtract(double a, double b);
        // Returns a * b
        MATHFUNCSDLL_API double __stdcall Multiply(double a, double b);
        // Returns a / b
        // Throws const std::invalid_argument& if b is 0
        MATHFUNCSDLL_API double __stdcall Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

The `__stdcall` calling convention is required to call functions from vba - By default the function will be compiled using the `__cdecl` calling convention. I would also switch out the return type to a `LONG` and then pass a pointer to a destination variable. You can use the return value to validate the function (if it throws an error or is okay)... Kind of like `HRESULT`.

[What is __stdcall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297654/what-is-stdcall) - The top answer has quite a good explaination of the different c/c++ calling conventions.