# Undefined reference to Fortran function in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, g++, gfortran

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    int __stdcall inhalf(int *);
}
int main()
{
    int toHalf = 2;
    int halved = inhalf(&toHalf);
    printf("Half of 2 is %d", halved);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, that looks good.

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
```

No errors.

```
! functions.f90
function inhalf(i) result(j)
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    integer             :: j
    j = i/2
end function inhalf
```

I'm pretty sure that's right.

```
$ gfortran -c functions.f90
```

So far so good...

```
$ gcc -o testo main.o functions.o
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `inhalf@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've been looking this up for over an hour, but I couldn't find anything that worked for this case. How should I solve this?

Comment: `inhalf` in fortran will be called `inhalf_` in c.

Comment: `inhalf@4` indicates, that there's still some unwanted mangling involved for the function declaration of `inhalf()`.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran question. Add a specific version where necessary to distinguish.

Comment: There is a whole tag about interfacing C and Fortran [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding]

Comment: @BoBTFish Not necessarily. The compiler might choose something else as a function name. You can even disable underscoring in most Fortran compilers.

Comment: I cannot even get the C++ file to compile.  "main.cpp:5:19: error: expected initializer before ‘inhalf’'

Answer (score 1):

For full C compatibility you can use the `bind` feature of modern Fortran:

```
! functions.f90
function inhalf(i) result(j) bind(C,name='inhalf')
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    integer             :: j
    j = i/2
end function inhalf
```

This allows you to give a name to the function that you can use in C (and others) without relying on the naming scheme your compiler uses on its own.

The `__stdcall` is Win32 only (and the default behavior for linking, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297654/what-is-stdcall)). You can safely remove it. [Actually it is required for compiling your code in Linux. ]

Comment: I guess there will still be the stdcall issue remaining.

Comment: @VladimirF stdcall issue? I tried this and it worked.

Comment: @robbie0630 your `__stdcall` can cause various things on 32bit windows. Notice the **@4** in `inhalf@4`